# Bash suppress output from builtin?

Tags: bash, stderr, io-redirection

Currently I am using a command like this

```
$ teststring=$(cat foo.txt 2>/dev/null)
```

This has **no output** regardless if the file exists, like I want. The following command does not seem to have a way to **suppress output**, if the file does not exist.

```
$ teststring=$(<foo.txt)
bash: foo.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ teststring=$(<foo.txt); } 2>/dev/null
```

The simple explanation is expansions are performed before redirections.

The technical explanation is that there is a [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) violation in Bash's redirection/assignment order. This special case is an allowable exception, but this isn't an issue in all shells, and the behavior can vary depending upon context. The above workaround should always work regardless.

Comment: +1 - ksh and zsh get it right (`a=$(<xyzzy) 2>/dev/null` does the right thing)